# "make clean" issue in MSYS/Cygwin

Tags: windows, makefile, recipe

I finally managed to compile a program in Windows, which took a while and would have not been possible without some help from here. It all works now, except: "make clean" yields

```
/bin/sh: del: command not found
Makefile:44: recipe for target `clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 127
```

In the makefile, the clean command looks like

```
clean:
del /S *.o *~ *.out [...], eliminating all resulting .o and executables resulting from make.
```

mingw64 is in the path, and I tried with `cygwin/bin` in the path and without, both with the same result. "Make" was done with `mingw32-make` in `msys`. I also tried "mingw-32-make clean" in `msys`, still no luck; I am also not sure if "make clean" is supported in Cygwin at all. I run the whole thing on Windows 7, 64 bit.

How can I fix this problem?

[image: Error with rm instead of del]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are mixing your platforms. [`del`](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) is a `cmd.exe` builtin, which is why it cannot be found by Bash. The analog to `del` is [`rm`](http://ss64.com/bash/rm.html).

Try running `make` under `cmd.exe`

or

editing the Makefile, replacing `del /S` with `rm -f`

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to create a file called makefile.defs in you project folder and overwrite the makefile variable RM which is automatically set to "del" by eclipse. The file is included by "makefile" in the [Name of Config] folder

my File just contains:

```
RM := rm -rf
```

This works fine for me.